# Problem with IIS, I do not see my Website from another computer

Tags: iis

I'm new to this but as the title says I have a problem, and mount my site in IIS

[image]

But the problem that I get when I try to access with the IP and the port 192.168.15.16:91 I get the following error

[image]

If someone can guide me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: That's a local IP - is the other computer on the same network? You should also check that your firewall allows IIS to open port 91 (which it may do with blanket permissions for all ports - I can't remember what the defaults are for IIS).

Comment: not the other computer is not in the same network, the idea is to access the site from either side

Comment: It has to be on the same network otherwise how does it communicate?